# character encoding issue - GB2312

Tags: java, character-encoding, gb2312

I am displaying simplified chines character retrieved from database using the below code snippet but it is displaying junk character

```
String text="×°ÏäÊ±ÇëÅÄÕÕ";  // retrieved from database 
String result=new String(text.getBytes("utf-8"),"GB2312");
```

Actual output is : �掳�盲�卤�毛����

Expected Output is : 装箱时请拍照

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string always should have the correct characters. Only during conversion to a byte stream the encoding comes into play.

So when `text` is what you got from the DB then you have the problem already in fetching the string from the DB.